# is it possible to have the time (in minutes and seconds) while converting audio to text with pocketsphinx

Tags: audio, time, translation, speech, pocketsphinx

I am using pocketsphinx to convert audio to text in ubuntu, the result contains text but to have also the time (in minutes and seconds) while converting audio to text with pocketsphinx, in addition to the generated text fromthe audio I want the time (in minutes and seconds) during which a word or phrase is pronounced. I am using this command :

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav 2> pocketsphinx.log > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -time yes -infile file.wav 2> pocketsphinx.log > result.txt
```